# xmlhttprequest return multiple values

Tags: javascript, php

How can i get Multiple Return Values in xmlhttprequest Method. or Suggest any Json Method to Retrieve Datas.

```
function getcustname(supplier)
{   
    if (supplier.length == 0){  
        document.getElementById("txtcustomer").value = "";
        return false;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            return_str = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (return_str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtcustomer").value = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("txtcustomer").value=return_str;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_results.php?required=buyprice&p=" + supplier);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a library like jQuery or something else which provides all the Ajax code? In jQuery, you can just use the $.ajax() function and set the response type to JSON. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is capable of replying with a set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and expect a JSON return value. By using jQuery, you also don't have to bother about the different browser ways to make an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://...",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result, status) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```